# Using Mongo ObjectId as an Index

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to iterate over an array retrieved from a `Model.find()` call.

```
const lists = ListModel.find();

const listSet = lists.reduce<Record<string, Set<string>>>((acc, list) => {
   const listId = list._id;

   acc[listId] = new Set()

   return acc;
}, {});
```

The `listId` is `new ObjectId(1234qwer1234qwer)` and the error is `Type 'ObjectId' cannot be used as an index type.` What is the ideal way to handle this? I will likely want to use the `objectId` reference at some point shortly after.

Edit: I have tried using `list.id` instead of `list._id` but had an error of `Type 'Buffer' cannot be used as an index type.`

Answer (score 2):

## Update:

You can use `._id.toString()` to get the stringified version of the ID, which you should be able to use as an index.

#### Original Answer

You can use `.id` instead of `._id` to get the stringified version of the ID, which you should be able to use as an index.

Comment: I originally tried that, but got `Type 'Buffer' cannot be used as an index type.`

Comment: @MichaelKoska How about `._id.toString()`?